# How do I speak text in a Mac app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am making an Xcode app, and I need to be able to push a button and have some text read.  If someone could provide me with the line(s) of code I would need to use inside the brackets of a IBAction button, that would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: @CodaFi: I wonder you did a mistake, Text-to-Speech, you voted to close for Speech-to-Text.

Answer (score 7):

Try this one:

You need a property

```
@property(strong) NSSpeechSynthesizer *speechSynth;
```

In your init method:

```
_speechSynth = [[NSSpeechSynthesizer alloc] initWithVoice:nil];
```

To start the speak:

```
- (IBAction)sayIt:(id)sender{
    NSString *string = [self.textField stringValue];
    // Is the string zero-length?
    if ([string length] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"string from %@ is of zero-length", self.textField);
        return;
    }
    [self.speechSynth startSpeakingString:string];
    NSLog(@"Have started to say: %@", string);
}
```

To stop the speak:

```
- (IBAction)stopIt:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"stopping");
    [self.speechSynth stopSpeaking];
}
```